# Hide and show a directive based on a button click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. So,please apologies for such a stupid question.

I want to hide/show a directive based on a button click .

```
<body ng-app="app"  ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to the world of directives!</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-clicked="itemClicked(fruit.label)" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <a>{{fruit.label}}</a>
                    <my-div></my-div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
             // Fruits
            $scope.fruits = [{
                    label:"Apple"
                },{
                    label:"Orange",
                },{
                    label:"Grapes"
                }];
        });

        app.directive('myDiv',function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',

                link : function(scope,elem,attrs){
                    scope.itemClicked = function(value){
                        alert('myDiv clicked : ' + value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

`Whenever a link in clicked` , I want to `show the alert with the respective fruit name` which comes from the directive function.

But no errors are as such in console.

What am I missing ?

Please give an explanation .

Comment: Shouldn't it be ng-click. You have used ng-clicked, just change that once and see if it works.

Comment: Damn !! It was just a typo. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Are you going to do something with the directive? You don't need it at all. Just put `$scope.itemClicked` function in your controller.

Comment: looks like `itemClicked()` function is defined within the scope of directive `myDiv` but your trying to refer it outside the scope of `<my-div>`, so why dont you add the click event handler to `<my-div>` element instead of  `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of define the function in directive define it in controller as below

```
app.controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
     // Fruits
    $scope.fruits = [{
            label:"Apple"
        },{
            label:"Orange",
        },{
            label:"Grapes"
        }];

    $scope.itemClicked = function(value){
        alert('myDiv clicked : ' + value);
    }
});

And also change ng-click="itemClicked(fruit.label)" in your html as well.
```